# How to achieve a "One UI" like Sliver AppBar using Flutter

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, appbar, flutter-sliver

Inspired by Samsung's new `One UI`, I wanted to implement something similar using `SliverAppBar` in Flutter. But I am unable to figure out...

As per One UI implementation, The SliverAppBar `title` should appear right in the center *(both vertically and horizontally)* of the expanded App Bar. At the same time, it should stick to the left when collapsed.

**NOTE:** In my case, the App Bar contains Background Image also... So, trying to wrap the `FlexibleSpaceBar` with `Column` widget seems to make the background look weird.

I also want to get rid of extra padding on the left (which is available by default even when no "leading" widget is placed) when collapsed. Also, it would be better if the actions appear at the bottom of the `SliverAppBar` when expanded, so that users can reach them one-handedly...

## One UI:

---

[image: Expanded SliverAppBar] [image: Collapsed SliverAppBar]

```
Left ⇒ Expanded:                    Right ⇒ Collapsed:
```

```
- Actions on bottom                 - Actions as usual
- title is centered                 - title is on the left
                                      (no unwanted padding on the left of title)
```

Comment: SliverAppBar is a material design app bar. If you want a custom design, use SliverPersistentHeader

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks a lot for that suggestion. I successfully implemented my custom AppBar... 

Comment: Could you share your code @MelvinAbraham

Comment: @willywijaya I didn't implement the exact "One UI" like appbar, rather I took a gist of it and tried to implement my own version. You can click [here](https://github.com/Melvin-Abraham/Expense-Monitor/blob/master/lib/appbar.dart) to view the code for my implementation of custom appbar. You just need to plug `MySliverPersistenceHeaderDelegate` in `SliverPersistentHeader` as its `delegate`.

Comment: life saving! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've created the [One Ui Scroll View](https://github.com/jja08111/one_ui_scroll_view).

You can also add `actions`, and customize any others.

Answer (score 0):

```
NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder:
        (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Palette.primaryBackgroundColor,
                    expandedHeight: 180.0,
                    pinned: true,
                    elevation: 0,
                    centerTitle: true,
                    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        centerTitle: true,
                        title: Text("Attachments", style: Styles.appBarTitle),
                    ),
                ));
```

You can use this to get the ONE UI look that you want.
The height can be changed on the expandedHeight.